# How to write join select query in Codeigniter query

Tags: codeigniter-3

How can I write following MySQL query in codeigniter. I tested the query and it worked as expected.

`select 
    p.post_title,
    count(d._id)
from 
    posts p
    INNER JOIN
    discussions d
    ON
    p._id = d.post_id
    INNER JOIN
    accounts a
    ON
    a._id = p.account_id
where
    a._id = '1494900911hRs5kjPXV9591a60afa434f'
group by
    p._id`

Comment: Just use `$this->db->query("YOUR QUERY HERE")`. From [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html).

Answer (score 0):

when you see documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) you can use **query builder class** to build your query. so your query builder will look like this:

```
$this->db->select('p.post_title, count(d._id)');
$this->db->from('post p');
$this->db->join('discussions d', 'p._id = d.post_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('accounts a', 'a._id = p.account_id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('a._id', '1494900911hRs5kjPXV9591a60afa434f');
$this->db->group_by('p._id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

then you can see documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) to **generating query result**

```
// get result.
$rows = $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('p.post_title, count(d._id) as count')->from('post p')->join('discussions d', 'p._id = d.post_id', 'inner')->join('accounts a', 'a._id = p.account_id', 'inner')->where('a._id', '1494900911hRs5kjPXV9591a60afa434f')->group_by('p._id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Get Result Data

```
$rows = $query->result(); // object format
$rows = $query->result('array'); // Array Format
```